# How to compare complexities of corpora?

Tags: nlp, measurement

I would like to compare how complex (varied or predictable) are my three corpora. They are from different topics, so some vocabulary is different, some is the same. Looking at one of the data sets it's clear that the syntax is more difficult than in the other two, sentences are longer, etc. I built word N-Gram language models using the SRILM toolkit (I'm new to language modelling) with the idea that I can then compare these models. One measure mentioned in relation to language models is perplexity. I'm confused about the following question: Can I just use perplexities of the three LMs directly as a measure of how varied are the corpora? The vocabulary and the sizes of the corpora are different, so now I think that this won't be a good comparison. I also built LMs from POS-Tags but the quality of the POS-Tagging result is not good because the language is from fora, has spelling mistakes, ungrammatical sentences and so on. What measures could be used to compare complexity of corpora from different domains? I'd appreciate your advise.
[I'm new to Stackexchange. I posted this on Crossvalidated, but I think maybe here is more appropriate forum.]

Answer (score 2):

> "I also built LMs from POS-Tags but the quality of the POS-Tagging result is not good because the language is from fora, has spelling mistakes, ungrammatical sentences and so on."

Aside from it being noisy, like you pointed out, you should think carefully about whether particular linguistic features are useful in your analysis. Does one corpus having proportionally more nouns move you toward what you want to learn about the corpora? Maybe in something like authorship attribution, but I can't really think of anywhere else that's effective.

If data sparsity is an issue, LSI can help by collapsing related terms together. This could also help with the spelling issues, collapsing poorly spelt words with their correct counterparts if they appear in similar contexts.

> "The vocabulary and the sizes of the corpora are different, so now I think that this won't be a good comparison."

It's not the end of the world. Having more data is always better, but you can work with what you have.

If you haven't chosen a language model yet, there's a few decisions you have to make:

- Are you going to smooth the data? How?
- Are you going to use an advanced technique to better exploit the data, such as [Latent Semantic Indexing (LSI)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing)?

You mention that you have a language model; I'm assuming your language model is a probability distribution such that `P(N-gram|topic)`. If this is correct, you've already normalized the data, so the two probability distributions should be readily comparable. Having more data would get you a more reliable result, but if your corpora are "big enough" to sample each topic reliably, you can move right into comparison.

As for comparison, try the [KL-Divergence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence). KL-Divergence is "a measure of the information lost when Q is used to approximate P." Less loss means that the corpora are more similar.   If you want a symmetric comparison, a "cheap" way to do it is to add `D(P||Q) + D(Q||P)`. Note, though:

> The KL divergence is only defined if Q(i)=0 ⇒ P(i)=0, for all i (absolute continuity).

So you'll *have* to smooth, in some manner.

Comment: I started with a basic setup in SRILM with Good-Turing discounting and backoff. I think I in principle understand, how they work. I have now also modified the input data sets like you suggested by correcting misspellings semiautomatically with aspell followed by manual correction. And created bigram and trigram models again. Perplexity returned lower than before; it is clear. With the KL-Divergence: I think I get the basic point of this measure. Except how to compute it when a word from one corpus doesn't appear at all in the other corpus. (tbc)

Comment: I think that from the KL-Divergence measure I obtain information on relative differences. I was thinking more about how to show that one data set "within itself" is more varied than the other. So for example the more varied data set is "harder" for classification tasks. How about splitting the three corpora into kind of "training/testing" subparts and then doing a KL comparison on several splits? Then I would know that the one that has the lowest loss is the most "internally predictable"; If you know what I mean. Does this makes sense? Thank you for the hints! Ed

Comment: "followed by manual correction" -> Well, *some* manual correction. For sure some misspellings remained but many irrelevant misspelling differences are not there anymore.

Comment: Not a bad move with the spelling correction. It might add a bit of error, but it sounds like it helps more than hurts, which is what you want. It may be worth reviewing the output to see which it seems to be doing more, just in case.

Comment: Your idea with splitting the corpus seems reasonable. More typically, when working on classification, computational linguists do a "hold-out," that is, they hold out a fraction of the data--say, 10%--then try to classify that 10% based on training on the other 90%. You could compare the corpus to itself, but if you intend to classify documents from different categories, just work on that task directly. If you want to measure the internal variance of a category, just use [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)). That will tell you how surprising the category is.

Comment: For KL-Divergence when a word doesn't appear, that's where smoothing comes in. In your probability distribution, you have to fill the gaps where a word from the other doesn't appear. Typically, this is done by adding some [integer value to each possible value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_smoothing).